# Use residue theorem to find $\int_C \frac{z+2}{(z^2-2z+1)^2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Use residue theorem to find $\int_C \frac{z+2}{(z^2-2z+1)^2}dz$

where $C$ is the semi circle in the right half plane of radius $R>1$ and diameter lies on imaginary axis. So here's what I have

$$\int_C \frac{z+2}{(z^2-2z+1)^2}dz=\int_C \frac{z+2}{(z-1)^4}dz$$

and I have to use

Res$(1,f)=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}((z-1)^mf(z))$

where $m$ for me is $4$ and my pole is at $1$. so do I take the $3$rd derivative of $(z-1)^4$ times the function inside the integral? But isn't that just $z+2$? Any hints or tips greatly appreciated!

Comment: That path $C$ is not a loop, and therefore the Residue Theorem cannot be applied.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Why isn't it a loop? it is a closed semi circle as I understand it. OP - If it is the case and $C$ is a loop, it's easier (or equivalent) to simply use Cauchy's integral formula in this case.

Comment: How can a semicircle be a loop? Its final point is not where it begins.

Comment: Check this [Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s55kxh4lst) I just made. Does your contour look like the green graph or the purple graph? If it's the green graph, then you can't apply the Residue Theorem. If it's the purple graph, then you can apply the Residue Theorem.

Comment: its the purple graph @Accelerator

Comment: Then you can use the Residue Theorem because that purple graph is a closed loop, assuming you are traversing the purple graph counterclockwise.

Comment: Note your integrand is $(z-1)^{-3}+3(z-1)^{-4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed the integral is zero.

You can see this using Laurent series too, as an alternative. In a very simple ways you have:

$$\text{res}\left(\dfrac{f(z)}{(z-1)^4}, z = 1\right) = \frac{1}{6} f^{(3)}(1)$$

But in your case $f(z) = z+2, hence the third derivative is zero.

Comment: ok cool that's what I thought too but wasn't sure.

Comment: Did you notice that $C$ is not a loop?

Answer (score 2):

> where $C$ is the semi circle in the right half plane of radius $R>1$ and diameter lies on imaginary axis

This is confusing. Fortunately from the comments, since you meant $C$ to be this [purple graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s55kxh4lst) and not the green one, the description of $C$ should be worded like, "$C$ is a semi-circle of radius $R>1$ in the right half-plane connected by a straight line on the imaginary axis that connects the two endpoints of the semi-circle." (Of course, this depends on what you consider a semi-circle as, but as far as Google Image results go, some people consider a semicircle as half of a circle without the line.) And you are assuming $C$ is being traversed in the positive direction, right?

> and I have to use
> Res$(1,f)=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}((z-1)^mf(z))$
> where $m$ for me is $4$ and my pole is at $1$. so do I take the $3$rd derivative of $(z-1)^4$ times the function inside the integral? But isn't that just $z+2$?

Yes, you would be left with just taking the third derivative of $z+2$, which is (obviously) $0$. Hence, the final answer is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your half-circle $C$ goes from $-Ri$ to $Ri$, then\begin{align}\int_C\frac{z+2}{(z-1)^4}\,\mathrm dz&=\left[-\frac{z+1}{2 (z-1)^3}\right]_{z=-Ri}^{z=Ri}\\&=-\frac{4iR\left(R^2-1\right)}{\left(R^2+1\right)^3}.\end{align}If $C$ goes from $Ri$ to $-Ri$, you just take the symmetric answer.

Comment: does this tend to $0$ as $R \rightarrow \infty$? as the bottom increases so rapidly.

Comment: Yes, it does tend to $0$.